# Server breaks on Naming.rebind

Tags: java, rmi

I'm doing an agenda on server and everything was going fine, I started the RMI registry and the server was working fine, I test the code and I was able to login. 
now I want to start putting the codes in methods and calling them in the client from the server,and when I put the `Naming.rebind("server", i);` in the server to call methods the code breaks.

My project is contain three classes: server, client and interface that calls the methods from the server to the client.  This is the code of the server:

```
public class ServerAgendas extends UnicastRemoteObject 
    implements InterfaceServer {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  protected ServerAgendas() throws RemoteException {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  static String Clientusername;
  static String Clientpassword;

  public static void main (String args[]) throws NotBoundException, 
      IOException {
    System.out.println("1");

    try{
      InterfaceServer i = new ServerAgendas();
      System.out.println("2");
      Naming.rebind("server",i);
      System.out.println("Serveur agendas pret");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
    }

    ServerSocket ASocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    Socket connectionSocket = ASocket.accept();

  }

  public boolean login(String ClientUsername, String ClientPassword) 
      throws IOException, SQLException {
  }
```

in the client side I use this to call the methods:

```
InterfaceServer i = (InterfaceServer)Naming.lookup("server");

System.out.println(i.login(username, password));
```

and the interface contain:

```
public interface InterfaceServer extends Remote{

    public boolean login(String Clientusername, String Clientpassword)
        throws RemoteException, IOException, SQLException;
```

I run the registry at first then I run the server, the console shows:

```
 1
 2
Error RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: InterfaceServer
```

I used the 1 and 2 to see where it is breaking, it is breaking on:

```
Naming.rebind("server",i);
```

What do I need to do to avoid this exception occurring?

Comment: What? How is this close reason justified? Can someone point out where the simple typo is? Why can't the problem be reproduced?

Comment: @Duncan maybe the question is _unclear_ to the closers so they guessed there was a typo, or it's so _broad_ some typo just has to be there.

Comment: @user3181052 Do not swear in your comments, they will be (and have been) deleted. I have not answered because I do not know the answer. Keeping calm and considering if you can improve your question is the way to handle this situation.

Comment: so you want to repost the question in more simple way????

Comment: you mean, hold people's questions in hands? We're not holding it in our hands, we have put it on hold. So that you can fix the issues that prevent it from being answerable.

Comment: @user3181052 I disagree with the other users and believe this is a valid question. I've voted to reopen and the question is now in the hands of the community. If others agree with me, it will get some more votes and will reopen. Then answers can be added. If people don't agree, it remains closed.

Comment: There are unfortunately people here who vote to close questions that they personally don't understand simply because they don't know anything about the technology in question, and without pausing to consider whether the question would be clear to someone who did. Fortunately there is a reopen button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class mentioned in the message isn't available to the Registry on its CLASSPATH.

The simplest solution to this and several other problems is to run the Registry inside the server JVM, with LocateRegistry.createRegistry().

Otherwise you will have to figure out how to start the rmiregistry command with a CLASSPATH argument, or else use the codebase feature, which is another kettle of fish altogether.